# idf.py is not working in linux virtual machine

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, terminal

I have been trying to follow this tutorial https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/c69f0ec/examples/peripherals/twai/twai_self_test

and I used the following link to setup the working elements https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/release-v3.3/get-started-cmake/index.html#step-1-set-up-toolchain

but i keep getting this error messages when I write the command

command

```
idf.py set-target {esp32s2}
```

error messages:

```
WARNING: Support for Python 2 is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
The following Python requirements are not satisfied:
gdbgui==0.13.2.0
Please follow the instructions found in the "Set up the tools" section of ESP-IDF Getting Started Guide
Diagnostic information:
    IDF_PYTHON_ENV_PATH: (not set)
    Python interpreter used: /usr/bin/python
    Warning: python interpreter not running from IDF_PYTHON_ENV_PATH
    PATH: /home/student/esp/esp-idf/tools:/home/student/esp/esp-idf/tools:/home/student/esp/esp-idf/tools:/home/student/esp/esp-idf/tools:/home/student/esp/esp-idf/tools:/home/student/esp/esp-idf/tools:/home/student/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? Have you tried to use Python 3?

Comment: I tried multiple solutions to fix it but it did not work

Comment: IDF Version 3.3 is not recommended for development anymore, AFAIK. Why are you using this old version? Can you switch to a new one? The current version 4.3 is built on python3 and should have less issues.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see, the "gdbgui" module has not been installed for python 2.

Can you try installing gdbgui with the command :

```
python2.7 -m pip install gdbgui==0.13.2.0
```

and try again ?

Comment: the following error appeared   ` Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bidict>=0.21.0 (from python-socketio>=1.6.1->Flask-SocketIO<3.0,>=2.9->gdbgui==0.13.2.0) (from versions: 0.1.5, 0.2.1, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.9.0rc0, 0.9.0.post1, 0.10.0, 0.10.0.post1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0.post1, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.14.2, 0.15.0.dev0, 0.15.0.dev1, 0.15.0rc1, 0.15.0, 0.16.0, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.17.2, 0.17.3, 0.17.4, 0.17.5, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.18.2, 0.18.3, 0.18.4)
No matching distribution found for bidict>=0.21.0 (from python-socketio>=1.6.1->Flask-SocketIO<3.0,>=2.9->gdbgui==0.13.2.0)`

Comment: @AsmaaAlyammahi My bad, there is another problem : I wanted to see if python2.7 could work with this module. It seems that it is not the case. The tutorial that you're following seems to be outdated. I think you should use python3 instead of python2.7